# How do I copy non shared files between Windows 7 computers?

Tags: windows-7, networking

Two computers running Win7 on a home network, let's call them `MyDesktop` and `MyLaptop`

From any one of them, I can see shared files on the other.

However, I want to supply my username and password on the other computer and copy **non shared** files on the other computer.

Let's say I'm using MyLaptop and want a file in MyDesktop

I have tried to map the other computer as a Network Drive; when asked for credentials, I give them my credentials as a full path: `\\MyDesktop\Leonel`. It runs forever, but is not able to connect. If I give the credentials for the laptop, it will only show the shared files.

How to proceed ?

Between Ubuntu computers, I can just `ssh` and `scp` files around. It's not as pretty as a  GUI, but it works... :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "hidden" share "C$" to access all of the harddrive:

> \MyDesktop\C$

You should, after giving your credentials be able to see all your files.

If both computers are in the same workgroup and you have the same user name and password on each you should connect straight through.

Answer (score 1):

when you're looking for network shares, you are only going to see shares, aka, shared folders with shared files. If you create an ssh server on your windows 7 box ([openssh](http://www.openssh.com) will work) then you'll be able to view/edit/copy files that you have made available to openssh.

Alternatively, you can create a local FTP sever, but again, you must specify the files that the server has access to, a decent option is [FileZilla server](https://filezilla-project.org/).